# How to add date variable to List of type String

Tags: date, arraylist, type-conversion

I have a date of `format yyyy-mm-dd`.

**Eg:**

```
Date a =new Date ( 2016-05-15);
```

This is fetched from the database . Now I need to add this date variable to a List. I am getting error if I am adding it directly to List of String

How do I do that. Please help.

Comment: which language you used?

Comment: Java technology